# IBM Websphere Application Server 7 - Why aren't threads that are hung destroyed?

Tags: java, websphere, threads, was7

If our application somehow loses connection with the memcached server all the threads are reported as hung after 10 minues or so

```
[28.04.11 16:50:15:831 CEST] 00000025 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread "WebContainer : 4" (00000029) has been active for 764759 milliseconds and may be hung.  There is/are 15 thread(s) in total in the server that may be hung.
```

I can't find any information on how to fix this. Shouldn't all of these threads be killed by the web container?

Answer (score 3):

There is no *safe* way to forcefully stop a Thread in Java. Please see [Why Are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend, Thread.resume and Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit Deprecated?](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) for more details.

The correct solution would be to for the application to set socket timeouts and/or stop its threads properly.